# why hive explain command always shows same result on different conditisions?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hive-partitions

I run below command to analyze table in hive.

```
analyze table my_partitioned_table partition(day='20230101') COMPUTE STATISTICS FOR COLUMNS
```

and when it finishes i try this to see explain before running query.

```
explain
select * from my_partitioned_table where day='20230101';
```

it gets

```
statistics: Num rows: 10250 Data size: 500000 Basic stats: Complete Column stats: None
```

the row count is correct.

when i try this

```
  explain
    select * from my_partitioned_table where day='20230101' and my_col1='test';
```

or this

```
  explain
    select * from my_partitioned_table where day='20230101' and my_col2='test2';
```

it gets same result , exactly half of before result :

```
statistics: Num rows: 5125 Data size: 250000 Basic stats: Complete Column stats: None
```

So what is the problem ? why it gets same result( wrong result about row count)